# How to do result biasing in Apache Solr by node rating?

Tags: search, rating

I have a site with Drupal 7 with [Apache Solr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) & [rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) module. In this site I have a content type that can be rated but search results are not being biased towards the better rated content.

If I go here: admin/config/search/apachesolr/env-solr/bias I found 3 kinds of biasing:

- result biasing
- type biasing
- field biasing

None of these sections/tabs give me an option to bias the search results to the content that has a better rating.

I know I can relate a View with the search and order the content by rating, but that's not biasing exactly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Apache Solr Voting API](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_votingapi) module is just what you're looking for. It seems to have grown out of [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/387050). In limited testing I found that enabling it does add a bias setting for vote rankings:

[image: Screenshot of Voting API solr bias settings]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know about this module. I'm going to try it.